# Вывод std::cout пропадает после работы с std::fstream

Tags: c++, stl

Ситуация удручающая, хотя причина будто бы где-то на поверхности (но я не могу ее увидеть). Вывод в консоль работает корректно до вызова функции, читающей и записывающей файл. Все данные из файла читаются корректно, то, что нужно, корректно записывается. Экземпляр `std::fstream ("doc.bin", std::ios::binary)` при вызове `rdstate()` выдает `0`, то есть ошибок нет. Пробовал вызывать `clear()` и `flush()` как у данного экземпляра, так и у `std::cout` и `std::cin` - безрезультатно.

```
std::cout << "ENTER:"; // выводится
initDocument();
std::cout << ":EXIT"; // не выводится
```

Comment: А может оно внутри initdocument крешится?

Comment: Где https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема крылась в вызове WinAPI для изменения кодировки консоли под капотом одной из вложенных функций.

```
 _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```